# How to keep Reading JSON file and refreshing Cache on AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, http, caching, get

I have a project on MVC which has uses angularJS.

This is currently my config file

```
app.config
(
    function ($httpProvider, $translateProvider)
    {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

        //initialize get if not there
        if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get)
        {
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
        }

        //disable IE ajax request caching
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = '0';
    }
);
```

You might notice that I have this on my code:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = '0';
```

I noticed a bug in Internet Explorer where if you load the page for the first time, it will load all data correctly, however if you add a record for example, next time you load the page it will keep the same view as the first time, unless you reset the cache. So that line of code helps that it will always refresh the site.

Now, I'm trying to read a JSON file:

```
$http.get('../App/Languages/en.json');
```

However, I get an Error 400.0 Bad Request;

I realized that if I removed the

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = '0';
```

and replace it with

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
```

the JSON file will be read correctly, however, that'd mean that I'll be removing the solution to the cache problem.

I have already tried adding both lines of code at the same time, but the JSON file is no longer being read.

Any suggestions on how should work around this?

Comment: `Content-Type` is atypical for a GET request header, as it generally applies to the body of the request/response, and there is no body on a GET request.

Try to figure out where the choke point is. When you use both lines, do you still see the request leaving the browser ? Does the request for the json file make it to the server ? Do the logs provide a reason for returning a 400 when it should give a 200 or 304?

Comment: Actually, I continued with the testing, and I discovered, the Content-Type has nothing to do with it... I removed everything, and it worked, I also added only a 
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
and it worked...

So I have figured, that the one causing this issue is the 

$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = '0';

SO, now how can I fix the Cache issue without messing with GETTING the JSON?